# Date/Time input for an HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, forms, input

I'm having trouble finding an elegant way to allow for date/time input in an html form. I am thinking of having drop down menus for year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond that are populated with valid entries only. I *could* do this by hard coding values for each drop down menu, but I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way to do this, perhaps with some already existing javascript library that I have not found yet. Any tips for getting this done?

edit: Second, and if possible, millisecond precision is needed for what I'm working on.

edit#2: After reading some of the comments, I have come to the realization that it is probably a bad idea to have drop down menus for the large range of values required by hours/minutes/seconds and especially milliseconds. I think will go with having the DatePicker prototype date chooser, along with a simple textfield for time input.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing why you need time input, especially milliseconds.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Will Rickards: I am developing a web application that displays logs that have millisecond precision timestamps. In this application, the user enters the start and stop date/time, and the relevant logs are displayed. New log entries are generated very frequently, sometimes more than once per millisecond, so precision is needed in specifying the timeframe over which to view the logs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done quite elegantly with a Jquery plug-in called [Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)

Comment: This is similar to what I'm looking for, but Datepicker doesn't support choosing times.

Comment: Mathew: I'm currently using Datepicker, and an additional textbox for selecting a time. It works well if it's simple/understandable.

Comment: alecwh: Do users enter the time by typing something like "12:00:00" into the textbox? This is what I'm currently doing, but I feel like it would be nice to have drop down select boxes to aid in error checking and prevent input typos by the user.

Comment: @Matthew: Ew, drop-downs for a large range of values? That's actually less usable. If possible, use a free text field and parse as wide a range of delimiters as possible.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use an input mask :
http://phenxdesign.net/projects/phenx-web/controls/example.htm
It works with PrototypeJS

Comment: @Rob, @Matthew: Choosing time can be quite easy using sliders. No excessive dropdowns... And you can have as many as you need: hour, minute and second if you like. Easy to use and understand and no clutter. Check this one out: http://milesich.com/timepicker/

Answer (score 4):

There are many calendars which can do this, with both date and time :

- [Calendar Date Select](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/)
- and others

Comment: These all look very good, and I am using the prototype js library, but I need something that has second, and if possible, millisecond precision. Sorry, I should have mentioned this before.

Comment: Well, I don't think there are any JS calendar able to give a millisecond precision, but Control.DatePicker could be a good basis to make your own millisecond-precision time selector !

Answer (score 1):

I think a very easy way to do this is by using PHP i.e. for making choosing a day and a month:

Use the `select` command for the form, then insert a PHP line to initiate a `for` loop. So for the days the loop would go from `1` -> `31` and for the month from `1` -> `12`. So instead of hard coding it for all the days months etc, you can neatly fit it into one line of code with a small bit of PHP added.